# How can I set up a keystroke in Atom to delete all whitespace before the cursor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macros, atom-editor

When editing the following code snippet in Atom, suppose my cursor is immediately before `my_parameter`:

```ruby
def a_method
  first_command               my_parameter
end
```

I want to use one keystroke to delete all of the space up to *but not including* any of `first_command`.  The default behaviour of `ctrl-backspace` in Atom is to delete not just the whitespace but all of `first_command`.  (This contrasts with other editors like Sublime Text which only delete the whitespace.)

What would be an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `delete-to-previous-word-boundary`, available from *Edit → Text → Delete to previous word boundary*.

Add this to your custom keymap (*Edit → Keymap...*) with your keystroke of choice.

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-backspace': 'editor:delete-to-previous-word-boundary'
```